# How to get Checkout page Json data in PaymentInformationManagement.php file?

Tags: checkout, custom, magento2.2.4

I have added 1 custom field to the payment step on checkout page.

To set this custom field data to quote posted at checkout time I am writing code in the file

```
Plugin/Model/Checkout/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php

Plugin/Model/Checkout/PaymentInformationManagement.php
```

I am not understanding that how to get this json posted data in above two files.

https://www.screencast.com/t/Xk5CZHpt

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the comment data in extension attributes and after this, you can get this posted data in

```
Plugin/Model/Checkout/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php

Plugin/Model/Checkout/PaymentInformationManagement.php
```

So for this create extension_attributes.xml in the Vendor/Module/etc directory and add below code in this file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface">
        <attribute code="comment" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

then Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/Checkout/PaymentInformationManagement.php

```
class PaymentInformationManagement {

protected $_quoteRepository;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
 */
protected $_jsonHelper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager
 */
protected $_filterManager;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper, \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager, \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
) {
    $this->_jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    $this->_filterManager = $filterManager;
    $this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
}

public function beforeSavePaymentInformation(
\Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement $subject, $cartId, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod
) {
    $orderComment = $paymentMethod->getExtensionAttributes();
    if ($orderComment->getComment())
        $comment = trim($orderComment->getComment());
    else
        $comment = '';
    $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
    $quote->setOrderComment($comment);

}

}
```

Vendor/Module/Plugin/Model/Checkout/GuestPaymentInformationManagement.php

```
class GuestPaymentInformationManagement
{

protected $_quoteRepository;

protected $quoteIdMaskFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
 */
protected $_jsonHelper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager
 */
protected $_filterManager;

/**
 * GuestPaymentInformationManagement constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\HistoryFactory $historyFactory
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
 */
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper, \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager, \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository, \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory
) {
    $this->_jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    $this->_filterManager = $filterManager;
    $this->_quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory;
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement $subject
 * @param \Closure $proceed
 * @param $cartId
 * @param $email
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface|null $billingAddress
 * @return int $orderId
 */

public function beforeSavePaymentInformation(
\Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement $subject, $cartId, $email, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod
) {
    $orderComment = $paymentMethod->getExtensionAttributes();
    if ($orderComment->getComment()):
        $comment = trim($orderComment->getComment());
        $orderComment = $this->_filterManager->stripTags($comment);
            $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($cartId, 'masked_id');
            $quote = $this->_quoteRepository->getActive($quoteIdMask->getQuoteId());
            $quote->setOrderComment($orderComment);

    endif;

}
```

}